# Errors After install Quill Editor

Tags: angular, typescript, quill, package-lock.json, ngx-quill

i get an error when i start project :  "npm start":

An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/.../node_modules/quill-mention'

i folowed the steps in  : https://mehulkothari05.medium.com/medium-like-text-editor-in-angular-quill-editor-38c0011a880b

my environnement :

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.9
Node: 14.18.0
Package Manager: npm 8.16.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 13.3.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.9
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.9
@angular/cdk                    12.2.13
@angular/cli                    13.3.9
@angular/material               11.2.13
@schematics/angular             13.3.9
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.6.4
```

any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. Delete node_modules folder
3. npm install

Let me know if that works. Its probably due to npm package lock.

Comment: Thanks @SETI for your replay; I changed the component, actually I use: @kolkov/angular-editor version 2.0.0 and it work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use acctually @kolkov/angular-editor version 2.0.0 for my project angular v13.X and it work fine for me